# warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input. How can I make gdb not ignore the null byte in the input?

Tags: c

The buffer overflow assignment I have has this code:

```
int zerg(char *arg)
{
    char buf[12];
    static int i, sum;

    if (strlen (arg) > 24) /* Argument too long! */
    {
        printf ("String too long!\n");
        return -1;
}
```

Which is why I used this as an input:

```
run "$(python -c "print 'RUSHKEKEKEzAS\00\xa9\x87\x04\x08'")"
```

But gdb is ignoring the null byte as input with the error above. How can I get pass this?

Comment: Your string has unescaped `"`, is that a typo or indicative of your actual debugging session?

Comment: actual debugging session.

Comment: And I suspect that when you properly escape things, the problem goes away?

Comment: I don't quite understand. Is it like this?:

Comment: run $(python -c "print 'RUSHKEKEKEzAS\00\xa9\x87\x04\x08'")

Comment: Which version of `gdb` …?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to put a NUL byte into a command-line argument, because the argument is terminated by the first NUL byte. When `execve()` copies the `argv` array into the newly-created memory space for the process to be run, it only copies up to the first NUL byte.

Since shells basically exist in order to feed command-line arguments to command-line utilities, they have no need to deal with embedded NUL bytes, and most of them don't. Bash, in particular, drops any NUL bytes it encounters during command substitution. Other shells might terminate the argument at the first NUL byte; the behaviour is unspecified by the Posix standard.

Since gdb is basically designed to mimic bash, it follows the same rules, as indicated by that warning message.